# How to align table data Right or left and color any row in HTML table from JSON Data

Tags: javascript, html, css

[fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/draj8126/vxfbLdp8/13/)

```js
    
    var tableValue = [
                      {
                         "5": "15942",
                         "6": "46456",
                         "7": "149079",
                         "8": "231616",
                         "9": "221235",
                         "10": "189642",
                         "11": "144417",
                         "12": "188025",
                         "13": "335321",
                         "14": "405479",
                         "15": "280150",
                         "16": "234051",
                         "17": "243563",
                         "18": "276148",
                         "19": "258459",
                         "20": "228403",
                         "21": "145696",
                         "22": "14966",
                         "OUTLET": "",
                         "BILLDATE": "TOTAL",
                         "TOTAL": "3608648"
                       },
                       {
                         "1": "0",
                         "2": "0",
                         "3": "0",
                         "4": "0",
                         "5": "605",
                         "6": "6073",
                         "7": "8324",
                         "8": "15596",
                         "9": "13424",
                         "10": "15865",
                         "11": "12101",
                         "12": "16792",
                         "13": "31889",
                         "14": "39439",
                         "15": "19949",
                         "16": "17571",
                         "17": "21105",
                         "18": "20803",
                         "19": "22551",
                         "20": "19865",
                         "21": "9632",
                         "22": "5",
                         "OUTLET": "JAYANAGAR",
                         "BILLDATE": "2018-08-01",
                         "TOTAL": "291589"
                       },
                       {
                         "1": "0",
                         "2": "0",
                         "3": "0",
                         "4": "0",
                         "5": "3736",
                         "6": "5177",
                         "7": "10598",
                         "8": "12227",
                         "9": "12020",
                         "10": "12329",
                         "11": "11412",
                         "12": "20662",
                         "13": "32000",
                         "14": "37438",
                         "15": "21690",
                         "16": "18499",
                         "17": "23042",
                         "18": "22779",
                         "19": "19878",
                         "20": "16754",
                         "21": "14371",
                         "22": "1513",
                         "OUTLET": "",
                         "BILLDATE": "2018-08-02",
                         "TOTAL": "296125"
                       
                     
                       }
                     ]
    

 function addTable() {
      var col = Object.keys(tableValue[0]);     // get all the keys from first object
      
     
          var countNum = col.filter(i => !isNaN(i)).length;        
         var num = col.splice(0, countNum);                            
         col = col.concat(num); 
         
       
         
                                                                        // shift the first item to last
                                                                        // CREATE DYNAMIC TABLE.
    var table = document.createElement("table");

                                                        // CREATE HTML TABLE HEADER ROW USING THE EXTRACTED HEADERS ABOVE.

    var tr = table.insertRow(-1);                       // TABLE ROW.


      for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
        var th = document.createElement("th");             // TABLE HEADER.
        th.innerHTML = col[i];
        tr.appendChild(th);
    }

                                                            // ADD JSON DATA TO THE TABLE AS ROWS.
    for (var i = 0; i < tableValue.length; i++) {

        tr = table.insertRow(-1);

        for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
            var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
            tabCell.innerHTML = tableValue[i][col[j]];
        }
    }

                                                              // FINALLY ADD THE NEWLY CREATED TABLE WITH JSON DATA TO A CONTAINER.
    var divContainer = document.getElementById("newTable");
    divContainer.innerHTML = "";
    divContainer.appendChild(table);
}
addTable()
```

```css
  table, th, td 
            {
                border: solid 1px #DDD;
               
               
            }
```

```html
<table id="newTable" class="table table-striped">
</table>
```

I am making a html table and the data for HTML table is coming from  Java end  in form of JSON from which i am populating my html table.

What i want is to align all numeric data to right and alphabetical data to left and want to color the text of a single row dark black.

Here below is my code

```
<table id="newTable" class="table table-striped">
</table>

    <script>

        var tableValue = [
                          {
                                "5": "15942",
                                "6": "46456",
                                "7": "149079",
                                "8": "231616",
                                "9": "221235",
                                "10": "189642",
                                "11": "144417",
                                "12": "188025",
                                "13": "335321",
                                "14": "405479",
                                "15": "280150",
                                "16": "234051",
                                "17": "243563",
                                "18": "276148",
                                "19": "258459",
                                "20": "228403",
                                "21": "145696",
                                "22": "14966",
                                "OUTLET": "",
                                "BILLDATE": "TOTAL",
                                "TOTAL": "3608648"
                              },
                              {
                                "1": "0",
                                "2": "0",
                                "3": "0",
                                "4": "0",
                                "5": "605",
                                "6": "6073",
                                "7": "8324",
                                "8": "15596",
                                "9": "13424",
                                "10": "15865",
                                "11": "12101",
                                "12": "16792",
                                "13": "31889",
                                "14": "39439",
                                "15": "19949",
                                "16": "17571",
                                "17": "21105",
                                "18": "20803",
                                "19": "22551",
                                "20": "19865",
                                "21": "9632",
                                "22": "5",
                                "OUTLET": "JAYANAGAR",
                                "BILLDATE": "2018-08-01",
                                "TOTAL": "291589"
                              },
                              {
                                "1": "0",
                                "2": "0",
                                "3": "0",
                                "4": "0",
                                "5": "3736",
                                "6": "5177",
                                "7": "10598",
                                "8": "12227",
                                "9": "12020",
                                "10": "12329",
                                "11": "11412",
                                "12": "20662",
                                "13": "32000",
                                "14": "37438",
                                "15": "21690",
                                "16": "18499",
                                "17": "23042",
                                "18": "22779",
                                "19": "19878",
                                "20": "16754",
                                "21": "14371",
                                "22": "1513",
                                "OUTLET": "",
                                "BILLDATE": "2018-08-02",
                                "TOTAL": "296125"


                              }
                            ]
        function addTable() {
             var col = Object.keys(tableValue[0]);     // get all the keys from first object


                 var countNum = col.filter(i => !isNaN(i)).length;        
                var num = col.splice(0, countNum);                            
                col = col.concat(num); 



                                                                            // shift the first item to last
                                                                            // CREATE DYNAMIC TABLE.
        var table = document.createElement("table");

                                                            // CREATE HTML TABLE HEADER ROW USING THE EXTRACTED HEADERS ABOVE.

        var tr = table.insertRow(-1);                       // TABLE ROW.


          for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
            var th = document.createElement("th");             // TABLE HEADER.
            th.innerHTML = col[i];
            tr.appendChild(th);
        }

                                                                // ADD JSON DATA TO THE TABLE AS ROWS.
        for (var i = 0; i < tableValue.length; i++) {

            tr = table.insertRow(-1);

            for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
                var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
                tabCell.innerHTML = tableValue[i][col[j]];
            }
        }

                                                                  // FINALLY ADD THE NEWLY CREATED TABLE WITH JSON DATA TO A CONTAINER.
        var divContainer = document.getElementById("newTable");
        divContainer.innerHTML = "";
        divContainer.appendChild(table);
    }
    addTable()

        </script>
```

this is my CSS

```
    table, th, td 
    {
        border: solid 1px #DDD;
        text-align: right;

    }
</style>
```

I just want to know how can i align the text left or right and how can i give the bold text or color any one of rows using javascript

[image: Check out this image for better understanding]

Comment: Post your css also.

Comment: Didn't understand what do you want to align to left. Are you talking about `Outlet` column or that particular value in the `Outlet` column, anyway both are already on the left.

Comment: @MuhammadAreeb i want to align that particular value of outlet left and all the values of TOTAL,1,2,3.... to right.

Comment: @MerajKhan i have posted..and please refer the image i have posted

Comment: @manishthakur To the bg color apply this `tr:nth-child(even) {background-color: #f2f2f2;}`  and for alignment inline-styling where you want add this in html`<td align="left">` or if you have css class you can give in css also.

Comment: @MerajKhan can you show me a running snippet please.

Comment: @manishthakur I have updated my code check it.

Answer (score 0):

In table add to tr same class as you used in header or just add below

```
style="font-weight:bold"
```

for the leftalign go to the td and add below

```
<td align="left">
```

Comment: by this all the table  data is left align and all the data is bold.. please refer the image.

Comment: you need to do only for the first tr and the first td only .... not for all

Answer (score 0):

Here I created sample code Hope this will help you. By default, every element takes float: left property.

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
}

th,
td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.right {
  float: right;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Points</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>jhon</td>
    <td>Griffin</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="right">Lois</td>
    <td>Griffin</td>
    <td>$150</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>Swanson</td>
    <td>$300</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Using jquery do like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#tablecontent tr:eq(2) > td:first-child').addClass('right');
     $('#tablecontent tr:nth-child(even)').css('background-color', '#cccccc');
});
```

Comment: yup bro you are right.. but  i am not giving data statically it is dynamic ..i am just giving <table> an id and populating the HTML table with JavaScript.

Comment: @manishthakur For my convenient, i wrote in a static way same logic you have to implement it dynamically in your js.

Comment: thats where i am stuck how can i do this with using js.. look i have added snippet also

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/draj8126/vxfbLdp8/13/ this is my fiddle link cn you please add into this only

Comment: it didn't worked..please check my fiddle and see if u can make some changes there.

Comment: Add jquery CDN here I used jquery.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182246/discussion-between-manish-thakur-and-meraj-khan).